# Alternative name of Shared Service in hyperion

Tags: hyperion, sharedservicesprovider, user-guide

I am new in Hyperion and currently studying about the Shared Services from user guide.
I have read  information about the shared services what is the task of shared services , I also gone through that . 
Now I have one question that is:

what is the alternative name of shared Services in Hyperion.
Please reply me .

Answer (score 0):

There is not an alternative name for Share Services.  Shared Services is a series of services shared across the Hyperion EPM suite that are a part of Foundation Services module.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/bi-foundation/shared-services-100533.html